# how to maintain double's precision in C++ Visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
main()
{
   double d1 = 1234.1;
   cout << "d1 = 1234.1 --> " << d1 << endl;
   double d2 = 1234.099999;
   cout << "d2 = 1234.099999 --> " << d2 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
d1 = 1234.1 --> 1234.1
d2 = 1234.099999 --> 1234.1
```

How can I get the exact value for d2 ?
Please suggest.

Comment: Aside from output rounding, keep in mind that `double` is not an exact numeric type to begin with.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same question twice: [How to maintain Double's precision in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191018/how-to-maintain-doubles-precision-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cout.precision(<number of digits after comma>);
```

like

```
cout.precision(5);
```

before output statement.