# Best way to convert double to string with significant digits (taking into account machine epsilon)

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to convert a double to string in c++.  I would like to format it using a certain minimum amount of significant digits, taking into account machine epsilon.

As an example for 2 minimum significant decimals:

4 -> "4.00"

4.4 -> "4.40"

4.56434444 -> "4.56434444"

I would ideally like to imbue a stream with a locale and a numpunct facet

I currently am using something like

```
if(abs(floor((m_mes * 100) + 0.5) - (m_mes * 100)) > (std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * 10000))
    buffer << fixed << m_mes;
else
    buffer << fixed << setprecision(2) << m_mes;
```

**EDIT:**
The absolute value and rounding are a result of compensating for epsilon.  The basic idea here is get floor(num * 100), subtract it from (num * 100).  If the difference is not zero, then I use a precision higher than 2.

since my minimum significant digits is 2 I didn't want to slow the algorithm down to accept a variable amount.

Is there a way to do this with a numpunct facet?  I am new to locales and have little experience with them.  Or just a more simple way to accomplish what I have?

Comment: I think your question makes no sense. How is `4.0` different from `4.000`, and how will you distinguish them?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think what he wants is a minimum precision of 2 but there should be no maximum.

Comment: @Caesar: Again, this makes no sense. What if I actually have significant digits that happen to be zero?

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think he would then complain as the work is done.

Comment: @Caesar You are right, I would not.  I am using this to output this already calculated data to the user

Comment: @KerrekSB Please see my edited explanation of the algorithm

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value) and [cppref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/)