# formatting a double value to 1 decimal place

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, boost

I'm new to C++ and am struggling with a piece of code. I have a Static text in a dialog, which I want to update on button click.

```
double num = 4.7;
std::string str = (boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(num));
test.SetWindowTextA(str.c_str());
//test is the Static text variable
```

However the text is displayed as 4.70000000000002. How do I make it look like 4.7.

I used `.c_str()` because otherwise a `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'LPCTSTR'` error gets thrown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'cout' the correct number of decimal places of a double value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.c_str()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why make things so complicated? Use `char[]` and `sprintf` to do the job:

```
double num = 4.7;
char str[5]; //Change the size to meet your requirement
sprintf(str, "%.1lf", num);
test.SetWindowTextA(str);
```

Comment: Well, in that case, why not simplify even further and make `num` itself a `char` array and 4.7 as string literal? Will this work if num = 123456? What would be the optimal array size of `str` is the value of num is not known at compile time?

Comment: @legends2k `char str[20]` can handle `double` and `long long`. It's not big size and already enough for C number types.

Answer (score 7):

Use of `c_str()` is correct here.

If you want finer control of the formatting, don't use `boost::lexical_cast` and implement the conversion yourself:

```
double num = 4.7;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setprecision(2) << num;  //the max. number of digits you want displayed
test.SetWindowTextA(ss.str().c_str());
```

Or, if you need the string beyond setting it as the window text, like this:

```
double num = 4.7;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setprecision(2) << num;  //the max. number of digits you want displayed
std::string str = ss.str();
test.SetWindowTextA(str.c_str());
```

Comment: @Madz Sorry, it's total nr. of digits, not decimals (see any [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)). So the correct value would be `setprecision(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact representation of 4.7 with type double, that's why you get this result.
It would be best to round the value to the desired number of decimal places before converting it to a string.

Comment: You mean **when** converting it to a string. Like you just said, there's no way to round it exactly *as a number.*

Comment: Is there a way to do it while converting to String? Can you explain please?

Comment: @Madz That's what my answer does.