# C++ equivalent of printf() or formatted output

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I am relatively new to the C++ world.
I know `std::cout` is used for console output in C++. But consider the following code in C :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    double dNum=99.6678;
    printf("%.02lf",dNum);
    //output: 99.67
 return 0;
}
```

How do I achieve the similar formatting of a double type value upto 2 decimal places using `cout` in C++ ?

I know C++ is backward compatible with C. But is there a printf() equivalent in C++ if so, then where is it defined ?

Comment: Use `setprecision` : `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << dNum;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'cout' the correct number of decimal places of a double value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << dNum;
```

and don't forget to :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
```

Answer (score 8):

There is **no** equivalent. It is a pain using `cout` for formatted output.

All suggested solutions calling `setprecision` and similar are awfull when using long formats.

`boost::format` does not support some very nice features. [Incompatibilities with printf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_differences). I still use `printf` because it is unbeatable.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there a printf() equivalent in C++ if so, then where is it defined?

C++23 added a similar formatting facility to C++ called [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print):

```
import std;

int main()
  std::print("{:.02f}", 99.6678);
}
```

On older systems you can use the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::print` is based on:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
  fmt::print("{:.02f}", 99.6678);
}
```

`std::print` and {fmt} use Python-like format string syntax which is similar to `printf`'s except for `{}` delimiters instead of `%`.

`std::print` preserves the type information so it is fully type-safe and doesn't need `l` and similar specifiers that convey type.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++23 `std::print`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `printf` like formatting you should probably use `snprintf` (or build an allocating variant of that on top of that). Note that `sprintf` requires you to be able to guarantee that the result will not overrun the buffer you have to keep defined behaviour. With `snprintf` on the other hand can guarantee that it will not overrun the buffer since you specifiy the maximal number of characters that will be written to the string (it will instead truncate the output).

You could even build something that can directly be fed to an `ostream` on top of `snprintf` by automatically allocate the buffer and place in an object that on destruction free that memory. This in addition with a method to feed the object to an `ostream` would finish it off.

```
struct FMT {
  char buf[2048];
  FMT(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
  }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, FMT const& str) { os << (const char*)str.buf; return os; }
```

then you use this as:

```
 cout << FMT("The answer is %d", 42) << endl;
```

If you're using the GNU libraries you could of course use `printf` directly since `cout` and `stdout` are the same object then. Otherwise you should probably avoid mixing `stdio` and `iostreams` as there is no guarantee that these are synchronized with each other.

Comment: If using GCC, you can give the constructor `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))`, to gain some compile checking of the types.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to reuse the same formatting techniques as in C, you may use [Boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html), which does exactly that:

```
cout << boost::format("%.02lf") % dNum;
```

Comment: Very good advice. Boost.Format mixes C-style flexibility, including the ability to provide the formatting dynamically, with C++ type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Save your program as `CPP` and run it.

It runs and prints the answer.

Because C++ also has the `printf()` and `scanf()` like `C`.

Comment: You should take care since `printf` prints to `stdout` which is not required to be in sync with `cout`. Using both `stdout` and `cout` is something that shouldn't be done unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sprintf in C++ to 'print' into a string and then cout that string. This strategy leverages your experience with printf-style formatting.

Comment: How is that better than just using `printf` directly?

Answer (score 0):

The functional equivalent of your `printf()` call, using `std::cout`, is

```
 std::cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << dNum;
```

It is necessary to `#include` `<iomanip>` and `<iostream>`.

The `printf()` equivalent in C++ is `std::printf()`, declared in `<cstdio>`.

Also, thanks to backward compatibility to C - specifically C++98 was required to maximise backward compatiblility to C89 - C's `printf()` declared in `<stdio.h>` is also available in C++.    Note, however, that `<stdio.h>` is deprecated (tagged for removal from a future version of the C++ standard).  Also, not all features of `printf()` introduced in C99 (the 1999 C standard) or later are necessarily supported in C++.

Comment: `printf` is **not** deprecated. `<stdio.h>` is deprecated in favour of `<cstdio`>, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

To output a value to the console using C++, you need the global ostream object **cout** and the **<<** operator. **endl** is another global ostream object used as line break.

All are defined in the `<iostream>` header file. You can also use various formatting flags to control the presentation of the output...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double dNum = 99.6678;

    cout << dNum;
    cout.setf(ios::scientific, ios::floatfield); // format into scientific notation
    cout << dNum;
    cout.precision(8); // change precision
    cout << dNum;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout` writes to stdout.   Often, stdout is associated with a terminal.  On very rare occasions, that terminal is a console.  'cout' is "character out", and is completely unrelated to a console.