# How to keep the precision of double variable in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

[It is not about printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value). It is about storing the value.

`int x = 1234;`
`double y = 0.3456;`

`double z = x + y;`

Currently `z` contains `1234.35`. I want `z` to contain `1234.3456`

What can be done to achieve this?

Comment: `z` contains an accurate value. You aren't printing it with sufficient precision.

Comment: if you're still having trouble, show the complete program that is producing the undesirable output

Comment: How are you viewing the value in `z`?

Comment: This question indeed deserves downvotes!

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius I agree. You've presented no evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does contain `1234.3456`. Check for yourself:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int x = 1234;
    double y = 0.3456;
    double z = x + y;

    printf("%.8f\n", z);
}
```

[Output](http://rextester.com/NQXIO20863):

```
1234.34560000
```

Comment: In other words, yes it is about printing (or formatting output) after all.

Answer (score 2):

The double accuracy contains a bit less than 16 decimal digits.
The printed value of z is less precise than the stored one.
If you want more than 16 digits, you should consider specific libraries like 
[mpfr](http://www.mpfr.org)

Comment: 15.9 decimal digits actually.

Comment: Depends on if you need the round-trip decimal to binary to decimal work. http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/

Comment: @EJP thanks, 15.9 is 53 / log_2(10).