# Please provide me the logic to print the result using PRINTF

Tags: c++, printf

need an programming logic to print an 4 decimal points

```
  EX: scalar should be 0 to -5   
  value = 10006 , scalar = -3 then print result = 10.0060 (4 decimals)  
  value = 123   ,scalar = -5  then print result = 0.0012 (4 decimals)**  
  required value/divisor = 10 , value%divisor = 0060 (required logic after decimals )
```

I tried like this:

```
 divisor =  std::pow(10,std::abs(scalar));

 **Result = snprintf(X,Y,"%d.%0*d",value/scalar,4,value%scalar);**
```

I'm not allowed to use  float , setprecision() .

It does not necessarily represent the actual value , but we can format that value to print with logic like the original one (by using the logic , add ...subtract...pow etc)

std::int32_t divisor = static_cast(std::pow( 10.0F,  std::abs( Scalar)) );

but int the above result modulus scalar value with 0 are not considering.
      **Please provide me the logic to print the above result with scalar condition

Comment: Almost duplicate of [How to 'cout' the correct number of decimal places of a double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value)

Comment: @user4581301 - i required that using printf , not by using any float , setprecision  or %C

Comment: You should be able to search the internet for [`printf` format specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), or any good C or C++ reference.

Comment: Does your "Note" mean: "I haven't used [these things]", or "I'm not allowed to use [these things]"?

Comment: @JerryCoffin - iam not allowed to use that float or setprecision()

Comment: What's your purpose in not using floating point?  School assignment?  Online Judge?  Most real life programming allows for division and floating point.  There are exceptions for constrained systems.

Comment: You probably want to clarify the requirements in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: Recommendation: watch out for `std::pow` it delves into floating point calculations deep inside and may result in a number like 9999.9999999 being returned in place of 10000. 9999.9999999  will then be truncated to 9999 and produce the wrong answer. When you are working in integers it's usually safer just to perform the multiplications yourself.  In this case you could use a look-up table or a `switch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'cout' the correct number of decimal places of a double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217510/how-to-cout-the-correct-number-of-decimal-places-of-a-double-value)

Answer (score 1):

In order to print decimals (easily), you need floating point:

```
printf("%10.6f", static_cast<double>(1) / 3);
```

If one of the arguments to division is floating point, the compiler will promote the expression to floating point.

Integral or scalar division will lose decimals.

You are always welcome to write your own division function.

**Edit 1: Shifting**
You don't need to use the `pow` function (especially since it's floating point).

Use a loop, in the loop multiply your divisor by 10 each time.

```
double result = (double) scalar / value;
int divisor = 10;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_DECIMALS; ++)
{
  // Isolate a digit using math.
  // print the digit
  divisor += 10;
}
```

The math part is left as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: thanks for your reply , Floats are not used . since it is the value iam using for Price calculations , so when i used float can't be compared further

Comment: "%c%5.2f" not allowed

Comment: Search the internet for "fixed point math c++".  You would have better precision with integers.  So in $US, one example is to represent number in pennies rather than floating point dollars.  Or in length, use millimeters.

Comment: Actually i know to print simple individual numbers into array and display numbers , which requires an array to store the string ..and one temp variable to store the individual value like this . while(num>=1) { temp= temp%10 ; printf("temp",temp) ;num=num/10 ; i++)  .........but in my scenario i should print all at once like this ...i should store the value in arr ........printf("%c.%c%c%c%c",value/divisor,arr[0],ar[1],ar[2],ar[3],ar[4]); BUT i am looking for simple logic

Comment: Please if u understood the problem , can u provide the logic

Comment: Try developing the logic yourself.  Take a number like 3.14159, figure out how to get a digit from it, such as multiplying by some divisor and subtracting from the original number.  Trust yourself, or search the internet for "c++ extract decimal digits".

Answer (score 0):

In this homework exercise you are expected to perform your own number formatting, rather than using that of a library.

For instance, to format and output 100 as "100"

```
int accum = 100;
int position = 0;
while (accum > 0)
{
   printf("%d", accum % 10);
   accum /= 10;
   position += 1;
}
```

For your homework assignment, you need to modify the above loop so that it puts a `printf(".")` in the correct place in the output number. Your answer is likely to involve multiplying `accum` before the loop and testing `position` relative to `scalar`